# Trying to Understand MVC4/Razor syntax and why things don't appear

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

It's clear that when I have a block like the following that no matter what @Model.ShowBottomBarOverride is set to, the div in the {} does not render.  I think it should but I just don't get it. I'm sure I'm somehow not understanding razor syntax processing

```
        @if (@Model.ShowBottomBarOverride)
        {

            <div id="sponsorBottomBar" class="hideOnSmallScreen">
                @{ Html.RenderPartial("_SponsorsBottomBar", Model); }
            </div>
        }
        <br />
```

Comment: @Model.ShowBottomBarOverride evaluates to false. Ergo nothing in side the block renders/runs etc...

Comment: Where is this code in relation to the main view?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the "@" prefix on the "Model" in the `IF` expression, but that code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

"`@`" means C# code, so, once you are in a code snippet you don't need it.

So, in your case you can simplify it this way:

```
@if (Model.ShowBottomBarOverride)
{
   <div id="sponsorBottomBar" class="hideOnSmallScreen">
       @Html.RenderPartial("_SponsorsBottomBar", Model)
   </div>
}
```

But I think your problem is that the `Model.ShowBottomBarOverride` is returning `false`. Try removing the `if` or harcoding a `true` condition.

Comment: When I debug, step over I step through the dive yet nothing goes to the Response

Comment: @PeterKellner, you don't get not even the sponsorBottomBar's Div ?

Comment: True.  I'm going to make a small test page.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the thoughts. Razor was acting as I expected, however I had a misplaced div that was causing my content to be invisible. I thought I had checked for that with DOM inspector but apparently I missed it.